# Pivot: How to do a subtotal (PRODUCT) then sum the subtotal on a new column?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-2013

i am using excel 2013 to create a pivot table to do a sub-total (on Field-B) and then using a sub-total (on Field-A) to add the subtotal values. As seen from below, The first part of subtotalling using PRODUCT is achieved. But when i tried to do the second 
subtotal, I got 400% and Excel will just add up the 4 raw values of 100%.

How do I actually ask Excel to display a value of 100% (adding value of 'Task 1 Product' to value of 'Task 2 Product') and in a new column pls?

Is it do-able? or do i need to do somersault?  TIA !

edit: the reason i am using pivot table is because i want to change the underlying data and have the pivot table reflect the updates via refresh.

```html
Field-A         Field-B     Field-C    Field-D
Process A       Task 1      Sub-1      0.0%
                            Sub-2      100.0%
                Task 1 Product         0.0% (*this is done*)

                Task 2      Sub-1      100.0%
                            Sub-2      100.0%
                            Sub-3      100.0%
                Task 2 Product         100.0% (*this is done*)

Process A Sum                          *i want 100.0% and not 400.0%* :(
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want the result of a mathematical operation equal to:

```
Task 1 Product + Task 2 Product
```

Which in this case is equal to 100%, then you need to do the following.

In the cell which intersects {Field-D} and {Process A Sum} you need to use the `SUM()` function, and refer it to the cells labelled {Task 1 Product}, and {Task 2 Product}.

If your grid is set up in your example with A1 as the cell with {Process A} in it, you need to enter the following in cell D10:

```
=SUM(D3,D8)
```

The same could be achieved with:

```
=D3+D8
```

Comment: doing this is not dynamic right as the pivoting of values can be dynamic... hmmm

Comment: What is your definition of 'dynamic' here? a 'dynamic' table in my experience is a table which updates the ranges of the formulas it queries as the table grows. As your question is currently written, dynamic tables are not mentioned, and from what I understand of your question you don't actually need pivot tables, so why make it complicated? :) you can edit your question to clarify by using the button on the bottom left.